# Issue Reloading DataTables with AJAX Result

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable, datatables

i am having issue with refreshing DataTable when i reload ajax data on radio button select event ajax result is updated but DataTable shows old Data
and it shows below message on console -

```
DataTables warning: table id=sample_1 - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3
```

i googled for this warning but nothing seems helpfull to me.

**below is js file i am using** 
[jquery.dataTables.js](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sgzzl2iup32sq3i/jquery.dataTables.js?dl=0)
[jquery.dataTables.min.js](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l4l7amvghaqje1w/jquery.dataTables.min.js?dl=0)
[table-data.js](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cesyrmv2km8u1hl/table-data.js?dl=0)

**below is my ajax method**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "manual-json.php",
    type: "POST",
    datatype: 'json',
    data: 'jobid=' + $('#jobid').val() + '&matchgroup=' + $('input:radio[name=matchgroup]:checked').val(),
    success: function(result) {
        alert(result);
        var res = "";
        data = $.parseJSON(result);
        for (var key in data) {
            if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                if (data[key].matchStatusID == 7) {
                    res = res + "<tr id='tab-row'><td colspan='4'><form id='formData" + i + "' onsubmit='formsubmit(this)' method='post' style='margin-bottom: 0;'><table width='100%'><tr><td width='34%'><input type='hidden' name='manualMatchResoulationDetailID' id='manualMatchResoulationDetailID' value='" + data[key].manualMatchResoulationDetailID + "'><input type='hidden' name='matchStatusID' id='matchStatusID' value='" + data[key].matchStatusID + "'><input type='hidden' name='processName" + i + "' id='processName" + i + "' value=''><input type='hidden' name='id' id='id' value='" + i + "'><input type='hidden' name='jobid' id='jobid' value='<?php echo $jobid; ?>'><label id='secondaryData' style='font-size:13px;'>" + data[key].secondaryData + "</label></td><td width='33%'><label id='primaryData' style='font-size:13px;'>" + data[key].primaryData + "</label></td><td width='16%'><label id='searchScore'  style='font-size:13px;'>" + data[key].searchScore + "</label></td><td width='17%'><button class='btn btn-blue' id='change" + i + "' type='button' style='padding: 2 2px;font-size: 13px;margin-right: 5px;margin-left: 10px; width: 58px;' onclick='matchprocess(" + i + ",this.id)'>Change</button><button class='btn btn-blue' id='unmatch" + i + "' type='button' style='padding: 2 2px;font-size: 13px;margin-right: 5px;margin-left: 10px; width: 58px;' onclick='matchprocess(" + i + ",this.id)'>Unmatch</button></td></tr></table></form></td></tr>";
                } else if (data[key].matchStatusID == 8) {
                    res = res + "<tr id='tab-row'><td colspan='4'><form id='formData" + i + "' onsubmit='formsubmit(this)' method='post' style='margin-bottom: 0;'><table width='100%'><tr><td width='34%'><input type='hidden' name='manualMatchResoulationDetailID' id='manualMatchResoulationDetailID' value='" + data[key].manualMatchResoulationDetailID + "'><input type='hidden' name='matchStatusID' id='matchStatusID' value='" + data[key].matchStatusID + "'><input type='hidden' name='processName" + i + "' id='processName" + i + "' value=''><input type='hidden' name='id' id='id' value='" + i + "'><input type='hidden' name='jobid' id='jobid' value='<?php echo $jobid; ?>'><label id='secondaryData' style='font-size:13px;'>" + data[key].secondaryData + "</label></td><td width='33%'><label id='primaryData' style='font-size:13px;'>" + data[key].primaryData + "</label></td><td width='16%'><label id='searchScore'  style='font-size:13px;'>" + data[key].searchScore + "</label></td><td width='17%'><button class='btn btn-blue' id='match" + i + "' type='button' style='padding: 2 2px;font-size: 13px;margin-right: 5px;margin-left: 10px; width: 58px;' onclick='matchprocess(" + i + ",this.id)'>Match</button><button class='btn btn-blue' id='unmatch" + i + "' type='button' style='padding: 2 2px;font-size: 13px;margin-right: 5px;margin-left: 10px; width: 58px;' onclick='matchprocess(" + i + ",this.id)'>UnReject</button></td></tr></table></form></td></tr>";
                } else {
                    res = res + "<tr id='tab-row'><td colspan='4'><form id='formData" + i + "' onsubmit='formsubmit(this)' method='post' style='margin-bottom: 0;'><table width='100%'><tr><td width='34%'><input type='hidden' name='manualMatchResoulationDetailID' id='manualMatchResoulationDetailID' value='" + data[key].manualMatchResoulationDetailID + "'><input type='hidden' name='matchStatusID' id='matchStatusID' value='" + data[key].matchStatusID + "'><input type='hidden' name='processName" + i + "' id='processName" + i + "' value=''><input type='hidden' name='id' id='id' value='" + i + "'><input type='hidden' name='jobid' id='jobid' value='<?php echo $jobid; ?>'><label id='secondaryData' style='font-size:13px;'>" + data[key].secondaryData + "</label></td><td width='33%'><label id='primaryData' style='font-size:13px;'>" + data[key].primaryData + "</label></td><td width='16%'><label id='searchScore'  style='font-size:13px;'>" + data[key].searchScore + "</label></td><td width='17%'><button class='btn btn-blue' id='match" + i + "' type='button' style='padding: 2 2px;font-size: 13px;margin-right: 5px;margin-left: 10px; width: 58px;' onclick='matchprocess(" + i + ",this.id)'>Match</button><button class='btn btn-blue' id='reject" + i + "' type='button' style='padding: 2 2px;font-size: 13px;margin-right: 5px;margin-left: 10px; width: 58px;' onclick='matchprocess(" + i + ",this.id)'>Reject</button></td></tr></table></form></td></tr>";
                }
                i = i + 1;
            }
        }
        res = restr + res;
        res = res + '</tbody>';
        $("#sample_1").append(res);
        TableData.init();

    },
    error: function() {
        $("#result").addClass('msg_error');
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `$('#sample_1').destroy();`

Comment: Why use both jquery.dataTables.js _and_ jquery.dataTables.min.js? 6 upvotes on a question with unreproduceable code?

Comment: "_i googled for this warning but nothing seems helpfull to me_", what about the warning itself - **For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3**??

Comment: That error simply means you're initializing datatables twice. Remove one of the datatables js files and make sure you destroy previous inits of datatables before initializing a new one. Other than that, cant tell you what might be going wrong here.

Comment: @markpsmith : yes .... not working

Answer (score 1):

If you try to call the main datatables method on a div that already has datables in it, it will fail, and not update the datables.

```
  /* Init DataTables -only works one time. */
  var oTable = $('#mytable').dataTable({
    //table options.
  });
```

After that, you are expected to call other methods, such as

```
oTable.fnReloadAjax()
```

or

```
oTable.fnClearTable( 0 );
oTable.fnDraw();
```

to reload the table after initialization.

So the first question I would ask myself is "am I loading datatables twice?" Well, you're certainly including two versions of datatables, the production version and the development version.

```
jquery.dataTables.js
jquery.dataTables.min.js
```

Firstly, only include one of these files.

The only way you can get around calling the specialized update functions is to completely destroy the datatable. This might be desirable if the datatable is so fundamentally different on each reload, that the update functions could result in stale columns or data. Be aware this will greatly cost in performance.

```
var $myTable = $("#mytable")
$myTable.dataTable().fnDestroy();    // destroy the old datatable
oTable = $myTable.dataTable({
//all your options.
});
```

More information about table reloading can be found in the documentation
http://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3